# Undefined method inside vue.js app returns no data

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

So I have a quick question, I'm wanting to return some data but for some reason I am unable to get any data to my method.

---

So I have the following `component` and `vue.js` app:

```
Vue.component('favorites-edit-component', {
   template: `
   <div class="column is-half">
      <button class="button is-fullwidth is-danger is-outlined mb-0">
        <span>{{ name }}</span>
        <span class="icon is-small favorite-delete" v-on:click="$emit('remove')">
          <i class="fas fa-times"></i>
        </span>
      </button>
    </div>
   `,
    props: ['name'],
});

new Vue({
    el: '#favorites-modal-edit',
    data: {
        new_favorite_input: '',
        favorites: [],
        next_favorite_id: 6,
    },
    methods: {
        add_new_favorite: function() {
            this.favorites.push({
                id: this.next_favorite_id++,
                name: this.new_favorite_input
            })
            this.new_favorite_input = ''
        },
        get_favorite_menu_items: function() {
            wp.api.loadPromise.done(function () {
                const menus = wp.api.collections.Posts.extend({
                    url: wpApiSettings.root + 'menus/v1/locations/favorites_launcher',
                })
                const Menus = new menus();
                Menus.fetch().then(posts => {
                    const test = posts.items.map(item => {
                        const items = {};
                        items['id'] = item.ID;
                        items['name'] = item.post_title;

                        console.log(items);
                    });
                });
            })
        }
    },
    created () {
        // fetch the data when the view is created
        console.log(this.get_favorite_menu_items());
        this.get_favorite_menu_items();
    },
});
```

---

So I want to be able to pull the data from the method `get_favorite_menu_items` and pass that to `favorites: []`.

For now, inside the `created ()` call, I'm getting a `undefined` result for `this.get_favorite_menu_items();`.

---

Inside my method, when I `console.log(items);`, I get the following return:
[image]

It's duplicating my objects, which is not what I want.. So this is what I want to be able to do:

1. Get the object from the method (Should be two only).
2. Build the objects inside an array and then pass the array to `favorites: []`.

When I `console.log(test)` this portion, I get the following return: `[undefined, undefined], [undefined, undefined]`.

```
Menus.fetch().then(posts => {
    // this.favorites = posts.items;
    const test = posts.items.map(item => {
        const items = {};
        items['id'] = item.ID;
        items['name'] = item.post_title;
    });
    console.log(test);
});
```

All help will be appreciated!

Comment: From what I can see, you aren't returning any value from get_favorite_menu_items.

Comment: @ThomasBay, I tried to `return $items` or even `this.favorite = items`, but still getting no results.

Comment: I think the reason you're seeing duplicated results is that you are calling `this.get_favorite_menu_items()` twice from `created` - once in `console.log` and once by itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Within your `map` you're not returning any value - try this instead:

```
this.favorites = posts.items.map(item => {
  const items = {};
  items['id'] = item.ID;
  items['name'] = item.post_title;
  return items;
});
```

Comment: Hey Hannah, thanks a bunch! Now when I `console.log(this.favorite)` outside `this.favorites = posts...` I have a single output of an array of objects! Woo. The second problems seems that the `created ()` method is still getting a undefined result back.

Comment: No worries! You could make your `created` method `async` e.g. `async created() { await this.get_favorite_menu_items() }` but since that method isn't returning anything you will still get an `undefined` result. But if you `console.log(this.favorites)` after that line I think it should work. Is that what you wanted to achieve here?

Comment: Sorry, I should add - you would also need to make `this.get_favorite_menu_items()` an async function.

Comment: So I converted it to `async get_favorite_menu_items() {` and then I also converted `async created () {` and then I'm `console.log(this.favorites);` inside `created()` and getting an object return `[__obj__]` with length 0. As you mentioned also, `await this.get_favorite_menu_items()` is still returning undefined. Sorry about all this, still a learning process for me.

Comment: Attaching a JSFiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/jmd1gvte/) if it makes things easier.

Comment: What if you add this to the end of your get_favorites method: `return new Promise(resolve => resolve(this.favorites));`

Comment: created is not async
https://forum.vuejs.org/t/cant-get-created-hook-to-work-when-its-async/28604